Quasar QCalendar Month view issue
I am trying to display month view (using quasar QCalendar) in my quasar app and it is always displaying it as "month-interval" (hours on the left and days 1 through 30 horizontally on the top).
I tried research the QCalendar Github but I can't find anything.
the version of QCalendar that I have is V4-beta16, and I am using quasar v2, I updated it and still the same issue, additional props maybe?? I know week and days work fine.
my code:
<template>
<q-page>
      <q-calendar
        view="month"
      />
  </q-page>
</template>

Any suggestions would be great... thank you!

Would you please provide an online playground?

what does "V4-beta16" refer to?  it's not quasar or vue, but you've not specified any other libraries you're using.  "I updated it", quasar? to what version?  Probably easiest to just include package.json so we have exact information.  "I reviewed github", was it a specific issue or page you can link?  Provide as much information as you can please.

the github link is: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-ui-qcalendar/issues, for qcalendar, I installed the v4-beta-16 version. I just want to display the calendar in month view and it doesnt, I only see month-interval view.

In QCalendar, you have 2 ways to set the exibition of the calendar as months.
I don't know what were you intending to show, but try using mode="month" instead of view="month".
See if that is yout issue, if not, please provide more details about what exactly do you want to achieve, so that we can provide more accurate answears.
Link to the documentation: https://qcalendar.netlify.app/developing/qcalendar
